# How do I get the data value from a button?

Tags: javascript, node.js, button

I am building a forum app in node and I would like to create big bright buttons on my home page that would route users to another /view (topic) when clicked on.

I would like to gather the value of the button pushed inside of an object,  so that I can use it within a dynamic route to be able to render to a specific view. I will also need that value to query with. Unfortunately I am having trouble getting the value of the button clicked.

Here are my buttons/inputs:

```
<form action='/topics' method="GET">

    <input type="submit" value="boy" id="boy" class="bounce topics">
    <button type="submit" value="girl" id="girl" class="bounce topics"><h2 class='topic'>Girl</h2></button>

</form>
```

when I console log req.body neither method gives me anything, I only get an empty object. I have read the two other threads I could find that were similar, but even though my code is comparable, I am getting nada.

Comment: Where is your tries? The code?

Comment: you using just raw javascript or something like JQuery?

Comment: for this I using both throughout the app...but for this just js

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `method` attribute in your form element needs to be `POST` instead of `GET`

Comment: you are right in that i am using a req.body for a GET, yikes, and though it is wrong, the problem persists upon setting a name attribute and using req.params.name (GET) and req.body (POST), and req.body.name - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may use either GET or POST in the method. The difference is that you will be retrieving them from the $_GET or $_POST global variables on the server side in PHP (or similar variables in the language of your choosing).

Instead of using "id" for each input element, you must specify names:

```
<input type="submit" name="boy" value="boy">
<input type="submit" name="girl" value="girl">
```

Comment: i actually JUST tried it with name, and because i am using a GET (I would like to reserve that POST route) I now see http://localhost3000?name=boy but what can i do to snatch that value as an object. req.params.name is returning undefined

Comment: also i am using node on the backend, and i am still fairly new to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access URL / GET variables via `req.query.<variablename>`.